# NSLocalizedString switching between languages

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslocalizedstring

My `tableViewCell` contains a label wich is localized via my macro:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

Im setting the labels text inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CELL_LABEL_TEXT", nil);
```

My app is localized for english and german:

```
//Localizable.strings (English)
"CELL_LABEL_TEXT" = "cool text";
//Localizable.strings (German)
"CELL_LABEL_TEXT" = "cooler Text";
```

This is not the only string that is localized in my app, all other strings work perfectly fine.
But somehow the labels text-localisation gets mixed up randomly (it seems) between english and german... (5 cells : en,en,de,en,en)
On the other hand im localizing another string inside the cell, but that one works...
Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?
(Device language is english)

**EDIT:**

```
myCustomCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"theCell"];

            if (!cell) {
                [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"theCell"];
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"theCell"];
            }
            cell.timestamp.text = [decoder stringFromDate:[post objectForKey:@"timestamp"] withIdentifier:kDateTimeline];
            cell.postDescription.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CELL_LABEL_TEXT", nil);
            return cell;
```

Comment: Can you show us your whole cellForRowAtIndexPath: method ?

Comment: You call "#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment)" 'yours' macros, but this is already existed macros in Foundation. Did you redefine it? Why?

Comment: I called it 'mine' because i'm explicitly `#define`ing it. To be honest, this is just a bad habit.